# how to have a where clause in an aggregate function SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

OK, I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID   AMOUNT      PAID
1    50.00       Y
2    100.00      N
3    200.00      Y
```

And I want to see something like:

```
Total     Due Paid
350.00    1   2
```

So my SQL would look like (in my head...it doesnt work that way, which is why I'm here )

```
select sum(amount)
,count(paid where paid='y') as due
,count(paid where paid='n') as paid 
from sometable where something=somethingelse
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select sum(amount) as total, 
       sum(case paid when 'N' then 1 else 0 end) as due, 
       sum(case paid when 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as paid
from sometable where something=somethingelse
```

Comment: Either add an `else 0` clause or change the `sum` to a `count`.  The version suggested in the question would have 0 if there were no values of that type.

Comment: @Gordon on balance I think `sum` is more readable here though a little less concise. Of course either would be fine as you say.

Answer (score 1):

One more option

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS Total,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN PAID = 'Y' THEN PAID END) AS Paid,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN PAID = 'N' THEN PAID END) AS Due
FROM sometable
WHERE something = somethingelse
```

Demo om [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0fa21/1/0)